# How to use variable in void to declare another variable Java?

Tags: java, void

So I'm making a Java Util and I am stuck on this part of code.

```
public void getInput(String i){
    int i = scan.nextInt()
}
```

Why won't this work?

Comment: Give your variables more descriptive names.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is there an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is already declared as `String` yet you redeclare `i` as an `int`. That can't work!

Comment: What I was trying to do about 3 months ago was use the name of String i to name the int. But, i chnged it around:

Answer (score 0):

You have two variables, which has the same name `i` but has the different type.

Change it like,

```
public void getInput(String i){
    int data = scan.nextInt();
}
```

and the Complier error will be gone.

Comment: But I need the String to be identified as i. So if a Dev types getInput(stackoverflow) it should ask for input and store it under int stackoverflow so they can case(stacloverflow)